# How to get maximum degree of parallelism for task parallel library usage?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I want to use Parallel.invoke. If i assign 20 parallel task, only 8 of then are run concurrently. My CPU is http://ark.intel.com/products/47925 and the reported number of threads is 8. I assume number of task can be run in parallel is related to the cpu number of threads. I dont want to create more task than the number of threads. How do i know the number of threads in c#? I tried query ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism and all i get is -1.

Comment: I highly recommend you go read "[Patterns of parallel programming](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19222)", it is a free ebook by microsoft for people just getting in to the task parallel library.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Parallel tasks are basically threads that can be shared. Because the number of active threads is limited by the number of logical processor cores that are available, a good guess would be to just take the number of logical cores available to the program.

```
Environment.ProcessorCount
```

Comment: you were right. that query gives me the same number to the number of threads. tried on different processor. but im confused. imho, the correct number of processor should be 1(i have 1 processor). the number of cores should be 4(my processor have 4 cores). 8 is the number of threads.

Comment: processors, cores, and logical cores are different. `Environment.ProcessorCount` contains the number of logical cores.

Comment: i think microsoft is the one that messed up the term. in tpl, logical cores are defined as threads while in system.environment, logical cores are defined as processor.

Comment: @publicENEMY Logical cores and threads are very different. You can have many threads in your application (much more than then number of cores), but the total number of running threads at any given time for all applications is limited by the number of logical processors.