# Parallel ForEach is too slow

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library, task

I am trying to make another web spider. For that I decided to go with tasks. I created little proof of concept. It works, but I think, it's somehow slow.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InitializeUrls();

        Start();


        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void InitializeUrls()
    {
        _random = new Random();

        List<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).ToList();
        foreach (int number in numbers)
            _urls.Add(number.ToString());
    }

    private static readonly BlockingCollection<string> _urls = new BlockingCollection<string>();

    private static readonly TaskFactory _factory = new TaskFactory();

    private static CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource;

    private static Task _task;

    private static Random _random;

    public static void Start()
    {
        _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _task = _factory.StartNew(
            () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Parallel.ForEach(
                        _urls.GetConsumingEnumerable(),
                        new ParallelOptions
                        {
                            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 100, //number of threads running parallel
                            CancellationToken = _tokenSource.Token
                        },
                        (url, loopState) =>
                        {
                            if (!_tokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
                            {
                                //here is the action
                                int waitTime = 5;// _random.Next(0, 15);

                                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("url {0}\ttime {1}\tthreadID {2}", url, waitTime,Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
                                Thread.Sleep(waitTime * 1000);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //stop

                                loopState.Stop();
                            }
                        });
                }
                catch (OperationCanceledException exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error when ending the operation", exception.ToString());
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("General exception", exception);
                }
            },
            _tokenSource.Token);
    }
}
```

As you can see I can set the number of threads running at once. When I set it to one, it works nice, it writes the url to console and it waits five seconds.
When I set it to 100, I expect it to create one hundred tasks immediatelly, but if you run it, it doesnt. It gets the urls very slowly. Do you have any idea why is this happening?

Comment: You're realistically not going to get 100 separate threads running. Here's a link to another stack overflow question regarding the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21520013/how-to-get-maximum-degree-of-parallelism-for-task-parallel-library-usage

Comment: Ok, I understand why this is limited to the number of cores I have (4).
But I thought I can have as many threads as I want running parallel.
I am pretty sure I have seen many tasks created each doing something else. Why is this construction different?

Comment: From my understanding you can have as many "tasks" queued up, but it's still bound to the number of threads the CPU can handle. I'm personally not qualified enough to explain in full detail, but there is a lot of information and theory regarding parallel computing out on the web. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

> When I set it to 100, I expect it to create one hundred tasks
>   immediatelly

And that is your mistake. The variable you set is not called "DegreeOfParallelism" it is called "**Max**DegreeOfParallelism". The `Parallel.ForEach` will start with a low number of tasks then start to ramp up as work completes up to the maximum you defined.

I highly reccomend you read the free E-Book "[Patterns of Parallel Programming](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19222)" by Microsoft. It goes over things like the behavior of `Parallel.ForEach` and more.

If you want to get 100 threads instantly you just need to use a normal ForEach and queue the work your self. You will need some kind of rate limiter to limit your max degree of parallelism.

```
var degreeOfParallelism = new Semaphore(100, 100);

foreach(var loopUrl in _urls.GetConsumingEnumerable())
{
    //If you are on C# 5 this line is not necessary.
    var url = loopUrl;

    if (_tokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        //Stop
        break;
    }

    //Takes one slot up in the pool of 100.
    degreeOfParallelism.WaitOne();

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) =>
    {
        try
        {    
            //here is the action
            int waitTime = 5;// _random.Next(0, 15);

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("url {0}\ttime {1}\tthreadID {2}", url, waitTime,Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
            Thread.Sleep(waitTime * 1000);
        }
        finally
        {
            //Release a item back to the pool.
            degreeOfParallelism.Release();
        }            
    });
}
```

However if you are doing a web crawler and are on .NET 4.5 you should not need to use threads at all. Instead use the `XxxxxAsync()` versions of the functions and you can keep a list of 100 Tasks and just do `Task.WhenAny(yourTaskList)` to detect when one finishes.

Answer (score 0):

If your work is CPU-bound, adding more threads than there are cores won't do any good.

If your work is not CPU-bound (eg, sleeping), you should use async (`await Task.WhenAll(stuff.Select(async s => await ...))`) instead, so you don't need any threads.