# C# parallel programming modifying xDocument

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, parallel-processing, .net-4.0, parallel.foreach

I never tried parallel programming before in c#.
So, before I jumped in, I wish I can get a fast answer to know if it worth delving into it, or not.
I have C# WCF web services applications with .NET 4.0. (it is possible to upgrade to 4.5 if parallel programming works)

All services are REST Services.
There is one service in particular that is taking sometimes very long time.
The service is processing and modifying an xml document.
the service accept an xml string as input, and give back the modified xml file.

The service does processing the xml in different locations, and different elements.
So, I created classes that inherits from an interface called IDocumentProcessor, and I have a list of those

The code briefly looks like this

```
interface IDocumentProcessor {
     void Process(XDocument doc);
}

public class DateProcessor : IDocumentProcessor
{
   public void Process(XDocument doc) {....};
}

public class CountryProcessor : IDocumentProcessor
{
   public void Process(XDocument doc) {....};
}


public class AddressProcessor : IDocumentProcessor
{
   public void Process(XDocument doc) {....};
}


public class AuthorProcessor : IDocumentProcessor
{
   public void Process(XDocument doc) {....};
}

....

Public class DocumentProcessorService
{
    public class ProcessDocument(string xmlFileAsString) 
    {
        var processorList = new List<IDocumentProcessor>{
            new DateProcessor();
            new CountryProcessor();
            new AddressProcessor();
            new AuthorProcessor();
        }

        var xDocument = XDocument.Parse(xmlFileAsString);
        processorList.forEach(x => x.Process(xDocument));
    }
}
```

so my fast question, and before I delve into making this parallel:
Can parallel computing modify the same xDocument object (in different locations)

and can this code be translated to do parallel computing with .net 4.0?

Comment: So you are trying to speed up the time it takes `ProcessDocument` to complete. How many times do you call this method (on different files) per second or minute? Maybe instead of making this method run faster, you can run more than instance of it on different documents?

Comment: We are running many instances of the service already.
We have load balancer.
But for some files (few giga bytes in size) the service takes sometimes 5 minutes

Comment: If you have let say 8 CPU cores, and you run 8 instances on 8 different threads, then making the loop inside the method run in parallel will not gain you any performance.

Comment: really? why? if I process dates in parallel while I am processing addresses, shouldn't make it faster?

Comment: You are already running multiple instances of the `DocumentProcessorService` class on different threads, right? You have a limited number of CPU cores. If you run 16 thread and your CPU has only 8 cores then every 2 threads would share a single core. This means that while one of these 2 threads is running, the other one has to wait.

Comment: Take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21520013/how-to-get-maximum-degree-of-parallelism-for-task-parallel-library-usage)

Comment: thanks a lot for your info.
I am not very knowledgeable on how IIS/ .NET WCF is distributed among processors.
What I know that our prod machine, each one has 6 processors divided by 3 virtual sockets, with each socket has 2 core.
How can I know, how many instances of wcf services are running, and if I can control that?
Any books or articles about this?

Comment: if you have files as big as few gigabytes you should reconsider your design

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From XElement documentation:

> Thread Safety
>   Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

It basically means that you cant modify an XDocument in parallel.

Another issue is that its not practical to fork on a type of operation on the same data.

This way its not scalable.

There might not be enough operation types to a fork for every CPU core and one type might finish much faster then the other. Also the contention is high.

If your document contains a collection of high level elements of a similar scheme, you could process their copies in parallel and then replace the old ones with the new ones.

The reassembly operation must be done in one thread and should not be too expensive if you choose the correct level of granularity.

You basically need a copy constructor for each XElement which is to be processed.

```
    var newElements = collectionElement.Elements().Select(el=>
    Process(new XElement(el))).AsParallel();

  var newCollection = new XElement("items", newElements);
```

Comment: this looks great.
I am excited to try it.
Thanks a lot
I will let you know what are the results.

Answer (score 1):

*Can* multiple thread modify instance of `XDocument` at the same time - yes, there is nothing explicitly stopping thread to make changes (unlike for example UI operations in WinForms/WPF).

But since `XDocument` type  is not thread safe class the results are completely unpredictable.

Correct implementation should prevent parallel access to the same `XDocument` (i..e using `lock` around access operations), as long as access is serialized you can change it from any thread.